# AngularJS filter array in array from json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

My data called from a JSON is very simple.

I want to filter all data where the id of events is 13

My json provides from `[...] $scope.things = things`

```
[
    {
     "id":"1",
     "title":"title1",
     "events":[
               {"id":"11",
                "events11"}, 
               {"id":"12",
                "events12"}
               ]
   },{
    "id":"2",
    "title":"title2",
    "events":[
              {"id":"11",
               "events11"}, 
              {"id":"13",
               "events13"}
             ]
  }
]
```

I try to display with :

```
 <ion-item collection-repeat="thing in things | filter:{events.id:'13'}">
    {{thing.id}}
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very 1st thing you need to correct you JSON format, like `events11`, `events12` & `events13` should be key value pair like such `"events": "11"`, "events": "12" & `"events": "13"`.

Then you could use deep filter like below.

**Markup**

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="thing in things | filter:{events: {id:'13'}}">
    {{thing.id}}
</ion-item>
```

[**Plunkr here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/97PPCUgxaOMLN8YQOqav?p=preview)

Comment: @JLRishe because haven't had changed in json, the JSON in question is invalid, you could check attached plunkr, though thanks for heads up man, cheers :)

Comment: I had fixed the broken JSON, but it must have not been working because my fiddle had Angular 1.0.1. I guess the deep filtering feature was added in some later version of Angular.

Comment: yes, If I remeber correctly, it have added since 1.3+

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar : instead of having an integer for id `{id:'13'}` i want to have a dynamic value `{events.id'}` how do that ? (to have a page per events.id)

Comment: I don't really fully understand.

Comment: instead of having `{id:'13'}` i need to have `{id:'events.id'}`, not the value 13 but a dynamic value

Comment: Well, you could directly pass scope reference there like `things | filter:{events: {id: events.id}}` assuming events.id has selected valuemm

Answer (score 0):

You could filter directly in the controller when instantiating the scope variable:

```
$scope.things = things.filter(obj => obj.id==='13');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with ng-if and a helper function:

```
 <ion-item collection-repeat="thing in things" ng-if="getEventInThing(thing, '13')">
    {{thing.id}}
</ion-item>
```

The following function will return the event with the given id, if present:

```
$scope.getEventInThing = function(thing, eventId) {
 return thing.events.find(function(event) {
  return event.id===eventId;
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <ion-item collection-repeat="thing in things">
    <span ng-repeat="event in thing.events" ng-if="event.id='13'"
        {{thing.id}}
 </ion-item>
```

Basically two loops with an ng-if for the inner loop to check if the even's id is 13.

Comment: what do you mean by `item.id == '13'`?

Comment: my bad, just a typo, changed it now